# Cannot invoke jsonObject with an argument list of type with: (Any), options: [Any]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've just updated to swift 3.1 and Xcode 8.3.1 and I struggling with an error which before the update wasn't an error. 
The error that I don't know how to solve is trying to parse json data from the API in the line `try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject`

I describe the code below

```js
public extension User {

    public static var fake: Resource<[User]> = Resource(request: { (url) -> URLRequest in
        var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)!
        components.path = "/v2/fake-users"
        var request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        return request
    }) { (data) -> ([User]) in

        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) >>>>ERRROR>>>> Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: (Any), options: [Any])'

        var code = json as? [String: Any]
        let error = code?["code"] as! String?
            if error == "NOT_AUTHORIZED_EXPIRED_TOKEN" || error == "INTERNAL_ERROR"{
                let sessionController = SessionController()
                sessionController.refreshToken(refreshToken: (SessionProvider().getUserToken()?.refreshToken)!) { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error trying to login refreshToken: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("login refreshToken successful")
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                print("\n code: \(error)\n")

            }
        let unboxer = try Unboxer(data: data as! Data)
        return try unboxer.unbox(key: "hits")
    }
```

Comment: It seems that the `data` parameter in the closure returns `Any` so you have to cast it to `Data` or declare the closure to a more specific type. By the way, you can omit the `options` parameter, the default value is *no options*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous reference to member \`jsonObject(with:options:)\` when trying to get data from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937336/ambiguous-reference-to-member-jsonobjectwithoptions-when-trying-to-get-dat)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

> }) { (strData) -> ([User]) in
>
> ```
> let data = strData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
>                 let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
>                 print(json)
> ```