# Ambiguous reference to member `jsonObject(with:options:)` when trying to get data from json

Tags: json, swift

I'm new to Swift and while making one of the tutorials (fairly old) which involves getting credentials from a server through php which returns a JSON, but I'm stuck with the error `Ambiguous reference to member jsonObject(with:options:)` in the json var, I've searched and trying applying the different solutions but to no avail. :(

Thank you for your time and help.

here is my code:

```
let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;

if((userEmail?.isEmpty)! || (userPassword?.isEmpty)!) {
    displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "All Fields are required.")
    return;
}

let myUrl = URL(string: "/UserLogin.php");
var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
request.httpMethod = "POST";
let postString = "email\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)";

request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
data, URLResponse, error in

    if error != nil {
        //print = ("error=\(error)");
        return
    }

    var err: Error?
    var json = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

    if let parseJSON = json {
        var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as String!;
        print("result: \(resultValue)")


        if(resultValue == "Success") {
            //Login Succesful
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);

        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: The error is that you have to omit the error parameter and implement do try catch error handling. Besides that casting URLRequest as URLRequest makes no sense. You forgot to include your url domain and scheme.

Comment: You should cast the json object to Swift native dictionary `as? [String:Any]` instead of using `NSDictionary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major issues:

1. The actual error occurs because the `response` parameter in the completion block is wrong. Rather than the type `URLResponse` it must be a parameter label / variable.

   ```
   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {  data, response, error in
   ```
2. Since you are using Swift 3 there is no `error` parameter in `jsonObject(with`. The method does `throw`, you need a `do - catch` block. And – as always – the option `.mutableContainers` is completely useless in Swift. Omit the parameter.

   ```
   do {
       if let parseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any],
          let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String {
             print("result: ", resultValue)

             if resultValue == "Success" {
                 //Login Succesful
                 UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"isUserLoggedIn")
                 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
             }
       }
   } catch {
     print(error)
   }
   ```

Some other notes:

- To check the text fields safely use optional binding

  ```
  guard let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text, !userEmail.isEmpty, let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text, !userPassword.isEmpty else {
      displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "All Fields are required.")
      return
  }
  ```
- Declare Swift constants always as `let` (for example `resultValue`)
- Do not use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift. Use native types.
- Do not use parentheses around `if` conditions and trailing semicolons. They are not needed in Swift.
- `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` is not needed either.
- `String.Encoding.utf8` can be reduced to just `.utf8`.

Comment: Wow thank you for your very explicative answer, I'm new to swift and almost all of the tutorials I found are outdated, I went with the Firebase Authentication route, but will use this answer for future reference as I plan to have the users on my own database. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Before using any non-trusted obscure tutorial please read the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309). It's worth it.